# Magento 2 - Dynamic custom validation error message not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, validation

i'm using Magento 2.4.1 and i add custom validation with a custom error message to detect which character is wrong and add it to the message:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    return function () {
        var validator = this;
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-unwanted-character',
            function (value,elm) {
                if (value.length != 0){
                    var regExp = /[a-zA-Z0-9\u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9f]/g;
                     if(!regExp.test(value) && value.length < 2){
                        var errorCharacter = value.replace(regExp, '');
                        validator.errChar =   $.mage.__('"%1" is an invalid character\'s, please correct your input.').replace('%1', errorCharacter)
                        return false;
                    }else if(!value.match("^[-A-Za-z0-9().\/ \u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9f]+$")){
                        var errorCharacter = value.replace(regExp, '');
                        validator.errChar =  $.mage.__('"%1" is an invalid character\'s, please correct your input.').replace('%1', errorCharacter)
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            },
            validator.errChar //this should contain the error message but always empty
        );
    }
});
```

i add this validation for firstname,lastname,company, and street in edit address form in frontend. However the error message is always empty

[image]

when i do  `alert(validator.errChar)` inside the `if` statement it is showing correct message , i pass the message to this variable so i can have dynamic message for each input element

Comment: Hi @jojo did you solve this issue ? If yes, can you please update the solution here please

Answer (score 0):

look like you missed $.mage.__('Your validation error message')

One thing you could try is to add a [JavaScript mixin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html): as below

In `requirejs-config.js` do:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and `Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/validation-mixin.js`:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-minimum-age',
            function (value) {
                // Some custom validation stuff here
                return true or false;
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
    }
});
```

This way your validation rule will extend the original JS validation object and will be available everywhere.

Comment: i store the validation message in validator.errChar variable

Comment: first try with static message "$.mage.__('Your validation error message')"

Comment: obviously it will show the message, if i replace the validator.errChar with $.mage.__ , i need to put the message inside a variable because i want the message content to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    return function () {
        var validator = this;
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-unwanted-character',
            function (value,elm) {
                if (value.length != 0){
                    var regExp = /[a-zA-Z0-9\u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9f]/g;
                     if(!regExp.test(value) && value.length < 2){
                        var errorCharacter = value.replace(regExp, '');
                        window.errChar =   $.mage.__('"%1" is an invalid character\'s, please correct your input.').replace('%1', errorCharacter)
                        return false;
                    }else if(!value.match("^[-A-Za-z0-9().\/ \u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9f]+$")){
                        var errorCharacter = value.replace(regExp, '');
                        window.errChar = $.mage.__('"%1" is an invalid character\'s, please correct your input.').replace('%1', errorCharacter)
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            },
            window.errChar;
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: got an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: errChar is not defined`

Comment: updated answer, try again

Comment: same result the window.errChar is empty